# Dart won't compile because of unmatching types, 'List<T>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<T> Function()'

Tags: dictionary, dart

The relevant part of the code looks like this:

```dart
  static final Map<String, List<Provider>> _availableProviders = {};

  Provider(this.name, this._requiresKey, this._versions) {
    _versions.forEach((version) => {
          Provider._availableProviders.putIfAbsent(version, <Provider>[]),
          Provider._availableProviders[version].add(this)
        });
  }
```

_versions is a set of Strings and when I try and run I receive this error:

```
lib/src/api/Provider.dart:18:71: Error: The argument type 'List<Provider>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Provider> Function()'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Provider' is from 'package:bible/src/api/Provider.dart' ('lib/src/api/Provider.dart').
          Provider._availableProviders.putIfAbsent(version, <Provider>[]),
```

`The argument type 'List<Provider>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Provider> Function()'`

I'm not exactly sure if this error has to do with the notation of the empty list I created or with how I instantiated the map. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you share `putIfAbsent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second parameter of Map's putIfAbsent is function, that returns value to be put, not value itself: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Map/putIfAbsent.html

Rewrite your code to something like this:

```dart
  static final Map<String, List<Provider>> _availableProviders = {};

  Provider(this.name, this._requiresKey, this._versions) {
    _versions.forEach((version) => {
          Provider._availableProviders.putIfAbsent(version, () => <Provider>[]),
          Provider._availableProviders[version].add(this)
        });
  }
```

Comment: Ahh, this is a case of "Read The Darn Manual" haha. Thank you!